# Setting up a Limited company online

Tags: united-kingdom, self-employment, private-company

I am going to set up a Limited Company for myself, as a sole owner. An accountant quoted me a good amount of money to do it. I have seen a number of online companies who say they help you do it for a fixed fee depending on the 'package' you buy. The can charge form only £12 to £200.

I have even found some of these companies in the TrustPilot reviews with several reviews. I do not want to put the names here in case I am accused of promoting companies but, if somebody tells me it is OK to do so, I can mention them.

Are they reliable or just cowboys looking for easy money?

Has anybody here used them?

Comment: Based on your wording and use of £ for currency I am assuming you are in the UK and have tagged the question accordingly. If this is not correct please comment or edit.

Comment: I've rolled back your edits as they removed the point of the question and in fact made it not a question at all. If you can explain what you were trying to do, I can try and help?

Answer (score 3):

How certain are you that setting up an LLC is something that would benefit you? How aware are you of how they work, what filings they need, etc?

If you are perfectly confident in the entire process, the value of well-qualified personal service is limited - what will they teach you if you know everything already?

But if like most people you have minimal exposure to these concepts before considering them for yourself, then you may find comfort in dealing with a person you can talk to, who can answer your questions, rather than an almost automated service that might do the job, but might not explain it to you in an understandable way.

Like most things, with financial services you get what you pay for - I suggest you even ask these accountants who you feel are charging too high, "What would be the benefit of using you instead of x service online for 10% of the price?". If you believe their answer, that settles it. If you doubt their answer, do more research on your own about the ideas they raise in response, and figure out if you agree with it or not.

Answer (score 2):

To set up a UK Limited Company, you go to the government website, and you'll pay £40 if I remember correctly. Here's their website:

https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/companies-house

Anyone else just wants to be a middle man and charge you money to fill out forms that you can easily fill out yourself.

Comment: (They *may* also provide useful services like explanations)